# FreeIPA Server Failing to Install Due to Encoding Failure

Tags: linux, centos, freeipa

I'm trying to install FreeIPA server on a CentOS 7 node. Starting with a clean image, I am running the following code (some unrelated parts not included):

```
        echo 'LANG=en_US.utf-8' >> /etc/environment
        echo 'LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8' >> /etc/environment

        yum -y install epel-release npm wget net-tools patch sbt python36u python36u-devel krb5-devel
        yum -y install python36u-pip

        yum install -y ipa-server

        systemctl start named
        systemctl enable named

        ln -s /bin/pip3.6 /bin/pip
        pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install kdcproxy ipaplatform gssapi ipalib

        ipa-server-install -p directoryManagerAdmin -a kerberosAdmin --ip-address=$ipaddress -n test.hadoop.com -r TEST.HADOOP.COM --mkhomedir -U
```

The ipa-server-install works properly until the part where it starts trying to use the web API. At this point, it fails due to an internal server error. Looking at the logs at /var/log/httpd/error_log, I found the following error replicated multiple times.

```
[Thu Jul 25 19:26:30.952879 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2934] mod_wsgi (pid=2934): Failed to exec Python script file '/usr/share/ipa/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jul 25 19:26:30.952929 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2934] mod_wsgi (pid=2934): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/ipa/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jul 25 19:26:30.953372 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2934] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jul 25 19:26:30.953402 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2934]   File "/usr/share/ipa/wsgi.py", line 48, in <module>
[Thu Jul 25 19:26:30.953406 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2934]     api.bootstrap(context='server', confdir=paths.ETC_IPA, log=None)
[Thu Jul 25 19:26:30.953414 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2934]   File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipalib/plugable.py", line 494, in bootstrap
[Thu Jul 25 19:26:30.953417 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2934]     raise errors.SystemEncodingError(encoding=fse)
[Thu Jul 25 19:26:30.953432 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2934] ipalib.errors.SystemEncodingError: System encoding must be UTF-8, 'ascii' is not supported. Set LC_ALL="C.UTF-8", or LC_ALL="" and LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8".
```

I've tried setting LC_ALL and LANG (as seen in the script), but it still comes up. What do I need to do to fix this so that the web API for the server will work properly?

EDIT: Per suggestions from @abbra @michael-hampton, I reverted my fixes for the Python issues. See below for the new set of commands I am running, plus one of the errors I am seeing in httpd/error_log. Note that I am seeing other packages missing as well, but they are all similar.

```
        yum -y install epel-release npm wget net-tools patch sbt krb5-devel

        yum install -y ipa-server

        systemctl start named
        systemctl enable named
```

Output in /var/log/httpd/error_log:

```
[Fri Jul 26 14:20:03.334411 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2894] mod_wsgi (pid=2894): Failed to exec Python script file '/usr/share/ipa/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jul 26 14:20:03.334456 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2894] mod_wsgi (pid=2894): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/ipa/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jul 26 14:20:03.334675 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2894] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jul 26 14:20:03.334697 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2894]   File "/usr/share/ipa/wsgi.py", line 43, in <module>
[Fri Jul 26 14:20:03.334701 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2894]     from ipaplatform.paths import paths
[Fri Jul 26 14:20:03.334716 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2894] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipaplatform'
```

Comment: Why have you installed a different version of Python and tried to make FreeIPA use it?

Comment: When I didn't do this, FreeIPA was installing Python 3.6 and using it, but then installing some of the libraries (the ones I install using pip) to the Python 2.7 version, so it would fail due to not having those libraries.

Comment: FreeIPA does not install Python 3.6 on CentOS 7. Use the version provided in the distribution -- ipa-server 4.6 is built against python 2.7.

Comment: @abbra then I'm confused. When I only had Python 2.7 installed, and then installed ipa-server through yum, Python 3.6 was installed as well. Additionally, Python 2.7 had the libraries that httpd was complaining about not having, such as ipaplatform and ipalib, and Python 3.6 didn't. This all led me to believe that it was using Python 3.6 for running the IPA HTTP server.

I ran yum deplist ipa-server | grep -i python, and found that the dependency mod_wsgi is using python36u.

Comment: @abbra I noticed this log message in the /var/log/httpd/error_log when I am not adding the libraries to Python3, which appears to confirm that some portion of the system is using Python 3. Any idea how to fix this? I've tried installing mod_wsgi straight up (hoping it used Python 2 instead), and it failed earlier on in the installation instead.

```[Fri Jul 26 12:44:07.215922 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2680] AH00163: Apache/2.4.39 (IUS) mod_auth_gssapi/1.5.1 mod_nss/1.0.14 NSS/3.28.4 mod_wsgi/4.6.2 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations```

Comment: You are probably having IUS repositories enabled. They provide packages that override and extend standard CentOS builds. As result, they make (in this particular case) your system incompatible with the requirements for IPA server packages. If you'd remove python36u-mod_wsgi, an original one (python2-based) will be picked up. However, I do not guarantee this configuration (CentOS + IUS packages) will work at all for FreeIPA as nobody tested it.

Comment: @abbra That makes sense. I'm using the centos/7 vagrant box, which is pretty basic, but I then install the IUS repositories I believe. I'll double check that this evening, and see if everything works if I don't install that repository first.

Comment: @abbra: That worked, somehow. Please make an answer to this question with that in there, and I'll mark it as complete so you get the credit for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably having IUS repositories enabled. They provide packages that override and extend standard CentOS builds. As a result, they make (in this particular case) your system incompatible with the requirements for IPA server packages. If you'd remove python36u-mod_wsgi, an original one (python2-based) will be picked up.

I do not guarantee this configuration (CentOS + IUS packages) will work at all for FreeIPA as nobody tested it.